# Get merged stderr and stdout output of junit tests when run from maven (surefire)

Tags: maven, junit, surefire

The surefire test plugin collects and reports the standard output and standard error separately in the report xml. This is quite confusing because usually both make sense when merged.

Is there a setting that enables surefire to generate the report with the stderr and stdout merged?

Comment: Did you already try this setting: _redirectTestOutputToFile_ (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile)?

Comment: I have the output merged anyway but for the whole run. I would like to get the xml reports merged too, since they are used by some tooling to generate human-readable reports for the single test cases.